# Why I get error with status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have one problem and unfortunately I cannot see error. The problem is following. I create Delete method and call that method in `AJAX` on button click.
But when I go to Index Page and try to delete item I get only error message which my swall aller dislay.

```
error: function (data) {
                        swal("Oops", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                    }
```

So far what I did, I create `Delete Action` in my controller

```cs
[HttpPost,ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Language language = db.Languages.Find(id);
    db.Languages.Remove(language);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

And in my `Index Page` I create this:

```
<div class="panel panel-flat">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-languages">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-blue">
                    <th>
                        Language Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Country Code (Flag)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="tr-id-@item.language_id">

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.code)
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <ul class="icons-list text-left">
                                <li class="text-primary-600"><a href="~/Languages/Edit?Id=@item.language_id"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="text-danger-600"><a class="delete_languages" href="javascript:;" data-id="@item.language_id"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my AJAX call:

```
<script>
    $('.datatable-languages').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columnDefs: [
            {
                responsivePriority: 1,
                targets: -1
            },
            {
                targets: [-1],
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                printable: false,
                width: "120"
            }
        ]
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete_languages', function () {
        var myId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log(myId);
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#FF7043",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        },
            function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Languages/Delete",
                    data: { id: myId },
                    success: function () {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); $('.child').remove() });
                        setTimeout(function () { swal("Deleted!", "Record deleted successfully!", "success"); }, 2000);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        swal("Oops", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                    }
                });

            })
    });
</script>
```

One notation before, I have try to remove AJAX call and in my Index Page I add this line of code, and It works

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BlogId }) <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BlogId }) <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BlogId })
</td>
```

Can anyone help me and tell me where I made mistake since I can not find, and have no idea where to start looking. Everything looks good but Item can not be deleted and in console I get error message

> Internal Server Error (500)

Comment: please try to replace your url by this : 
`url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',  
dataType: 'json',`

Comment: In my script ? In AJAX call ?

Comment: you can add try catch in ActionResult then you must debug, check your message on catch.. if cant debug, please your ajax

Comment: Probably `DeleteConfirmed` is throwing an exception. As you don't have any exception handling there, the fallback of the framework is to return a generic 500 error ... Try adding some exception handling in your delete handler

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

> ```
>  return Json(new { success = true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
> ```

After deleting ajax will go back to the success method but after deleting you are trying to redirecting it, So, it's giving you the error of 500.
Ajax has the property that it does not reload your page and perform backend tasks and then you can reload that list that you want to update.